# Android Recycler View not showing full height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview

My existing code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollmain">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HAT0"
                android:id="@+id/HAT1"
                android:paddingTop="4dp">

                -----Text View ------

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/HAT2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HAT1"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal">

                ----- Text View ---------

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HAT2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using this code the `RecyclerView` is not covering the whole bottom layout.If I dont mention any minimum height then I cant see RecyclerView. So I need to specify a height to `RecyclerView`. So what should  I do to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `android:fillViewport="true"` attribute to your `ScrollView` and set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for your `RecyclerView` , you will fix your problem.

Like that :

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollmain">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/HAT2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`NestedScrollView` is the answer in 2020. Please use it instead of `ScrollView` if you put a RecyclerView inside